# Categorize customers into buckets based on criteria

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a dataframe with Customer_ID and Invoice_date and I want to convert each customer into either Active, New, Loss or Lapsed category. The data is present from July 2021 to June 2022 (12 months_)
The criteria for each split is as:

- Active customer = Customer present once in (Apr, May, Jun 22) & once
  in (Jul 21 to Mar 22)
- New customer = Customer present just for (Apr, May, Jun 22) and no
  other month
- Lapsed customer = Customer present just for (Jan, Feb, Mar 22) and
  not for (Apr, May, Jun 22)
- Lost customer = Customer present from (Jul to Dec 21) and not for
  (Jan to Jun 22)

So far I have tried to create a function using the below code

```
max_date = F.max(more_cust.INVOICE_DATE)
two_months = F.date_sub(more_cust.INVOICE_DATE, 60)
three_months = F.date_sub(more_cust.INVOICE_DATE, 90)
six_months = F.date_sub(more_cust.INVOICE_DATE, 180)
one_year = F.date_sub(more_cust.INVOICE_DATE, 360)
def recency_bucket(df1):
    customer = dict()
    df1 = df1.sort("INVOICE_DATE", ascending=False)
    var_date = df1.rdd.map(lambda x: x.INVOICE_DATE).collect()
    cust_list = df1.rdd.map(lambda x: x.CUST_ID).collect()
    customer = customer.withColumn("CUST_ID", df1.collect[0]["cust_list"])
```

I want the output to look like this:

[image]

Comment: @maggie I am thinking of including one more bucket i.e. dormant i.e. Active customers who have not purchased in the last two months i.e. Customers who purchased from Jul 21 to Apr 22 and not in May 22 and Jun 22. They should only be active customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can categorise your invoice date in quarters say 1(jul to sep 21), 2(oct to dec 21), 3(jan to march 22), 4(april to june 22).

Invoice data

```
cust_id invoice_date
c1      2021-07-05
c2      2022-02-01
c2      2022-05-10
c3      2022-02-01
c4      2022-04-10
```

Invoice data with quarter

```
df = df.withColumn("quarter", F.quarter("invoice_date")).withColumn("quarter", F.when((F.col("quarter")+2) > 4,
                                                                                  (F.col("quarter")+2) % 4).otherwise(F.col("quarter")+2))
```

```
+-------+------------+-------+
|cust_id|invoice_date|quarter|
+-------+------------+-------+
|     c1|  2021-07-05|      1|
|     c2|  2022-02-01|      3|
|     c2|  2022-05-10|      4|
|     c3|  2022-02-01|      3|
|     c4|  2022-04-10|      4|
+-------+------------+-------+
```

Create pivot table and define rules based on bucket criteria and categorise customers

```
cust_quarter = df.groupBy("cust_id").pivot("quarter", [1,2,3,4]).count().fillna(0)
cust_quarter.show()

+-------+---+---+---+---+
|cust_id|  1|  2|  3|  4|
+-------+---+---+---+---+
|     c1|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|     c4|  0|  0|  0|  1|
|     c3|  0|  0|  1|  0|
|     c2|  0|  0|  1|  1|
+-------+---+---+---+---+

new = ((F.col("4") > 0) & (F.col("1") + F.col("2") + F.col("3") == 0))
active = ((F.col("4") > 0) & (F.col("1") + F.col("2") + F.col("3") > 0))
loss =  ((F.col("1") + F.col("2") > 0) & (F.col("3") + F.col("4") == 0))
lapsed = ((F.col("3") > 0) & (F.col("1") + F.col("2") + F.col("4") == 0))


bucket_rules = F.when(new, "new").when(active, "acitve").when(loss, "loss").when(lapsed, "lapsed")
cust_quarter = cust_quarter.withColumn("bucket", bucket_rules)

cust_quarter.show()

+-------+---+---+---+---+------+
|cust_id|  1|  2|  3|  4|bucket|
+-------+---+---+---+---+------+
|     c1|  1|  0|  0|  0|  loss|
|     c4|  0|  0|  0|  1|   new|
|     c3|  0|  0|  1|  0|lapsed|
|     c2|  0|  0|  1|  1|acitve|
+-------+---+---+---+---+------+
```

Comment: I am thinking of including one more bucket i.e. dormant i.e. Active customers who have not purchased in the last two months i.e. Customers who purchased from Jul 21 to Apr 22 and not in May 22 and Jun 22. They should only be active customers.